# Do answers have to be on one line?

Tags: support, answers

I was going to submit an answer but it would have to import a module (which is built-in to Python). This makes my answer two-lined, because of the import. Is this acceptable?

Comment: no, but in most languages (not python though) it's shorter.

Answer (score 9):

Of course it is acceptable. :)

Your answer can span as many lines as you like (in fact, there are many languages used around here where *most* programs have to span multiple lines). Just add the required linefeeds to your byte count. Simple example:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Would be 11 bytes. (Unless the program requires a trailing linefeed as well, in which case it would be 12 bytes, but I don't think you'll have to worry about that in Python.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll submit the answer :)

Comment: Oops. I won't accept it...

`Built-in constants that contain 9 or more of the above characters are disallowed.`

Comment: Your comment seems to be quite out of context. If you are asking with regard of a specific question please link it.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. [Question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85666/print-all-alphanumeric-characters-plus-underscore/85686)